# Is it possible to store documents in Ubuntu One and edit them online?

Tags: ubuntu-one

Microsoft Office Web Apps has SkyDrive; Google Docs also has storage.  Is it possible to store documents in Ubuntu One and edit them online from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu One storage is about to close -

[Ubuntu One - Shutdown](https://one.ubuntu.com/services/shutdown/)

Look elsewhere for your storage needs. If you need to edit online, Google Docs is proably your best bet.

Answer (score 7):

Currently this is not possible, but it is a good idea, and one you should suggest to the ubuntu-one developers.

Comment: Is that where I am supposed to submit it?

Comment: That is a good place to suggest it, as far as I know the Ubuntu developers take a lot ideas from brainstorm.ubuntu.com.

Comment: My original idea was marked as a duplicate of this one: http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/27060/